# Discuss the continuity and differentiablity of given function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

If $\big[\cdot\big] $ denotes floor function (i.e the integral part of $x$) and $$f(x)=\big[x \big] \left(\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{\big[x+3\big]}+\sin \pi \big[x+3\big]}{3+\big[x \big]} \right)$$, then choose the correct option:

$A.$ $f(x)$ is continuous on $R$

$B.$ $f(x)$ is a periodic function.

$C.$ $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in R$

$D.$ $f(x)$ is discontinuous for all integers.

One thing I can see is that $\sin \pi \big[x+3\big]$ will be 0 for all $x$ so we will be left with  $$f(x)=\big[x \big] \left(\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{3+\big[x \big]}}{3+\big[x \big]} \right)$$

Could some one suggest how to proceed further?

Comment: Isn´t A wrong since [x] itself is discontinuous at every integer?

Comment: Hint:  for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ except $n=-3$ we have $f(x)$ constant for $x\in[n,n+1)$. For $x\in[-3,-2)$ we have $f(x)$ undefined, although I suppose there are ways of giving it a meaning.  (This assumes the "integral part" of $-{5\over 2}$ is $-3$; others might see it, I suppose, as $-2$.)

Comment: Well, obviously f(x) =f (n) for n <= x < n+1 for all integers.  If f (n) ne f (n+1) for any n then f is discontinuous at n.  Obviously the occurs so A is out. So C is out because to be differential a function must be continuous.  If you can show f (n) never equals f (n+1) then D must be so.  Periodic is exceedingly unlikely. Sin [x+3] is always 0.  Sin pi/[x+3] decreases